# DbFit can't connect and find fixture in SetUp page

Tags: installation, fitnesse, dbfit

I installed DbFit on my laptop and connected it to my local Oracle Database. 
I did the initial setup:

```
!path lib\*.jar

!|dbfit.OracleTest|

!|Connect|localhost:1522|system|Test123!|ORCLE|

!|Query| select 'test' as x from dual|
|x|
|test|
```

This worked fine (after lots of errors and using StackOverflow).

Now for a more clean look and since it's needed for every page I moved this part to the SetUp page which will be automaticly included in every page I create:

```
!path lib\*.jar

!|dbfit.OracleTest|

!|Connect|localhost:1522|system|Test123!|ORCLE|
```

When I then try to run I get the following message:

1. Could not find fixture: dbfit.OracleTest. (This is for !|dbfit.OracleTest|)
2. Could not find fixture: Connect. (This is for !|Connect|localhost:1522|system|Test123!|ORCLE|)
3. Could not find fixture: Query. (This for the query select 'test' as x from dual)

Anyone has any idea? The only simulair issue I found was here:
[Why cannot DbFit be imported in SuiteSetUp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781394/why-cannot-dbfit-be-imported-in-suitesetup)

But this didn't give me any solution.

Thank you for looking at this issue and your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I expect the problem is that the !path line should be in the parent page and not on the setup.

Comment: This fixed it! In my mind it didn't seem logical because I expected the setup page needed the !path line to find the fixtures.

Thank you so much!